# extract filename with extension from codecommit repo through aws cli

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

I try to get all filenames from codecommit repo through aws cli.

If we use command

```
aws codecommit get-folder --repository-name reponame --folder-path ""
```

we can get output like this

```
{
"commitId": "2915c5a2eab08aeb36facbb1dc78b7f3f6f10873",
"folderPath": "",
"treeId": "0cc6d2dcfa75acd0bceacd446674635d44be0ab7",
"subFolders": [],
"files": [
    {
        "blobId": "8e29296c9119a5c5d839bc3d910b065c5cce0629",
        "absolutePath": "filename.yaml",
        "relativePath": "filename.yaml",
        "fileMode": "NORMAL"
    }
],
"symbolicLinks": [],
"subModules": []
}
```

And I should get a full filename of "filename.yaml". I think I can get this through bash, but now I can't understand how it's possible.
Could you please help me?

If I find an answer, I will definitely share it here.

Comment: Please complete the next time what you have tried to answer the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this to your command:

```
| jq -r '.files[].absolutePath'
```

Output:

```
filename.yaml
```

---

See: `man jq`